# Is this "types may not be defined in a for-range-declaration" notification erroneous?

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the following:

```
#include <vector>
struct Foo { int a, b; };
int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) {
    std::vector<struct Foo> foos = { {4,5} };
    for (struct Foo const& foo : foos) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Clang, ICC, and MSVC all compile it without incident.  However, GCC 6.2 outputs:

> warning: types may not be defined in a for-range-declaration

This did not occur in 6.1, and it has become an actual error in 7.  However, it looks to me like `struct Foo` was defined on line 2.  Is this warning/error therefore erroneous?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the 'struct'?

Comment: Even though this may be a compiler bug, I'd classify this firmly as a Doctor Doctor type situation.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Then it compiles just fine. However, our style guides recommend always using `struct` if the structure was defined using `struct`.

Comment: Seems, g++ is breaking with C (`struct Foo` is a valid type)

Comment: This is "warning" in gcc 6.2 for me  - are you using a switch to convert it to an error ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, GCC is doing a stupid thing. [Page 162 of the C++17 standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf#page=162) says that the first part of a range-based for loop (the _for-range-declaration_) shall not define a class or enumeration. Looks like GCC's interpreting `struct Foo` as a new declaration of `Foo` and acting accordingly.